# Alternative for ImmutableMap.of()

Tags: android

In my project I'm using the following code:

```
        List<Map<String,?>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(ImmutableMap.of("icon", R.drawable.icon1, "label", getString(R.string.title1)));
        data.add(ImmutableMap.of("icon", R.drawable.icon2, "label", getString(R.string.title2)));
        data.add(ImmutableMap.of("icon", R.drawable.icon3, "label", getString(R.string.title3)));
        data.add(ImmutableMap.of("icon", R.drawable.icon4, "label", getString(R.string.title4)));
        data.add(ImmutableMap.of("icon", R.drawable.icon5, "label", getString(R.string.title5)));
```

I want to know if there's a similar way to do that without using guava ImmutableMap 'cause I need to remove it from my dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, define a class and create an `ArrayList` of that class.

**Example:**

```
public class DataHolder {

   // declare the variables String, int, String, String

   public DataHolder(String str1, int drawableID, String str2, String str3){
     //initialize the class variables with the values passed in constructor
   }


}
```

Then create an `ArrayList<DataHolder> ad` and add your objects to it:

```
ad.add(new DataHolder("icon", R.drawable.icon1, "label", getString(R.string.title1));
ad.add(new DataHolder("icon", R.drawable.icon2, "label", getString(R.string.title2));
ad.add(new DataHolder("icon", R.drawable.icon3, "label", getString(R.string.title3));
ad.add(new DataHolder("icon", R.drawable.icon4, "label", getString(R.string.title4));
```